# Is there a workaround for "recursive instantiation error" in Qml?

Tags: qt, recursion, qml, instantiation, qt6

I have a situation which I need a component which holds a ListView of its own type. Here is a simplified version:

**myComp.qml**

```
import QtQuick

Item {
    Text {
        id: name
        text: qsTr("Hello")
    }

    ListView{
        model: 5
        delegate: MyComp{}
    }
}
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    MyComp{

    }
}
```

**qmldir.txt**

```
MyComp 1.0 myComp.qml
```

After running this, I get `recursive instantiation error` which is expected.

My main questions are:

- Is there a workaround to overcome this issue?
- What is the general approach if you want to implement such thing? for example what should I do if I want to implement something like the query builder UI provided [here](https://querybuilder.js.org/)?

Comment: "*Is there a workaround to overcome this issue?*" Simple: do not use a type inside the type itself. What you are doing it akin to filming a TV that displays what you are filming: it ends up with an endless cascade of the same image included into itself..."*[...] if you want to implement such thing*" And what is it that you are trying to implement exactly?

Comment: You can use [Loader](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-loader.html) and set its source to the file itself like `Loader { source: 'myComp.qml' }`. Additionally, you can use [DelegateChooser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-delegatechooser.html) in combination with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Atmo mentioned in the comments, you cannot declare a type in itself. However, in your case, an infinite loop will not occur.

As far as I know, there are two options for solving your problem:

1. Use a Loader item, as mentioned in [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194553/broken-recurssive-instantiation-checks)].
2. Set the delegate during component declaration.

### 1. Loader

The simplest option is to use a Loader [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39194553/broken-recurssive-instantiation-checks)]. I also suggest using [DelegateChooser](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-delegatechooser.html) to switch between delegates, as you don't need to use a Loader on all sub-items and write conditions, etc.

For example:

**Group.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels

Control {
    id: control

    property alias model: listview.model
    padding: 5

    DelegateChooser {
        id: chooser
        role: 'type'

        DelegateChoice {
            roleValue: 'data'
            Control {
                required property var modelData
                padding: 5

                contentItem: Row {
                    spacing: 5

                    Repeater {
                        model: modelData.data
                        Label {
                            required property string modelData
                            padding: 5
                            width: 35
                            text: modelData
                            background: Rectangle {
                                radius: 2; border { width: 1; color: '#ccc'}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                background: Rectangle {
                    radius: 5
                    border { width: 1; color: '#eee'}
                }
            }
        }

        DelegateChoice {
            roleValue: 'group'
            Loader {
                required property var modelData
                source: 'Group.qml'
                width: control.availableWidth
                onLoaded: item.model = modelData.data
            }
        }
    }

    contentItem: ListView {
        id: listview
        implicitHeight: contentHeight
        spacing: 5
        delegate: chooser
    }

    background: Rectangle {
        color: '#aafbf3dd'
        radius: 5; border { width: 1; color: '#dcc896'}
    }
}
```

And usage is like:

```
Group {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: [
        {type: 'data', data: [1,2,3]},
        {
            type: 'group',
            data: [
                {type: 'data', data: [4,5,6,7]},
                {type: 'data', data: [8,9,10,11]},
                {type: 'group', data: [{type: 'data', data: [12,13,14]}]},
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

**Preview**:
[image]

### 2. Move Delegate to outside of file

This is a cleaner approach, as it doesn't require a **Loader**, but it does require using multiple files, which is fine. Here is a simplified example:

**Group.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Control {
    id: control

    property alias model: listview.model
    padding: 5

    property Component delegate: Item {}

    contentItem: ListView {
        id: listview
        spacing: 5

        implicitHeight: contentHeight
        delegate: control.delegate
    }

    background: Rectangle {
        color: '#aafbf3dd'
        radius: 5; border { width: 1; color: '#dcc896'}
    }
}
```

**Delegate.qml** (simplified version)

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import Qt.labs.qmlmodels

DelegateChooser {
    id: chooser
    role: 'type'

    DelegateChoice {
        roleValue: 'data'
        Row {
            required property var modelData
            spacing: 5
            Repeater {
                model: modelData.data
                Label {
                    required property string modelData
                    text: modelData
                }
            }
        }
    }

    DelegateChoice {
        roleValue: 'group'
        Group {
            required property var modelData
            width: ListView.view.parent.width - 10
            model: modelData.data
            delegate: chooser
        }
    }
}
```

The usage remains the same:

```
Group {
    anchors.fill: parent
    model: [ /* same data */ ]
    delegate: Delegate {}
}
```

**Preview**:
[image]