# How could I make a Expand All / Collapse All function for my custom QML TreeView?

Tags: qt, qml, treeview, qt5

For a Qt project based on Python for the backend and QML for the frontend, I made a custom component used to display data as a tree structure. This component uses a ListModel, the name of the field in the model where the name of the data is stored (so I can reuse this component for any model I have), the name of the field in the model containing the id, and the name of the field of the model containing the data's parent ID (for the same reason).

Each data can have a parent, so the component handles this by displaying a round button on the data row if the data has at least one child, and not displaying it when a data has no children.

The component is using Qt's Loader component to handle the recursion of the data's display.

I would like to understand how I could implement an **expandAll** and **collapseAll** function with my current method of handling data hierarchy, and furthermore, how would I be able to display data based on its id, for example:

```
name: "Data 1", id: 1, parentId: 0
|
|
|________ name: "Data 2", id: 2, parentId: 1
|        |
|        |
|        |________ name: "Data 3", id: 3, parentId: 2
|
|
|________ name: "Data 4", id: 4, parentId: 1
         |
         |
         |________ name: "Data 5", id: 5, parentId: 4
```

For example, how would I be able to make my tree structure display "Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 4" and "Data 5" if I would like to see the "Data 5" ? In this way, I mean how could all the above parents of a data use the expand method declared in my code so the entire path leading to a specific data would be displayed ?

Here is the code I'm currently using. Many thanks to [Stephen Quan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/881441/stephen-quan) who helped me understanding how to display data's in QML in a previous post :

main.qml :

```
//Edit : Added a simple example of customerDataModel :

ListModel {
    id: customerDataModel

    ListElement {
        CustomerID: 1
        CustomerName: "Google"
        CustomerParentId: 0
    }
    ListElement {
        CustomerID: 2
        CustomerName: "Amazon"
        CustomerParentId: 0
    }
    ListElement {
        CustomerID: 3
        CustomerName: "Amazon US"
        CustomerParentId: 2
    }
    ListElement {
        CustomerID: 4
        CustomerName: "Amazon EU"
        CustomerParentId: 2
    }
    ListElement {
        CustomerID: 5
        CustomerName: "Amazon FR"
        CustomerParentId: 4
    }
    ListElement {
        CustomerID: 6
        CustomerName: "Apple"
        CustomerParentId: 0
    }
    ListElement {
        CustomerID: 7
        CustomerName: "Apple NTH"
        CustomerParentId: 6
    }
}

OctopusTreeView {
    id: customerTreeView
    width: 500
    height: 500
    dataModel: customerDataModel
    dataId: "CustomerID"
    dataName: "CustomerName"
    dataParentId: "CustomerParentId"
}
```

OctopusTreeView.qml :

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    property var dataTable: ([])
    property var dataModel: []
    property string dataId: ""
    property string dataName: ""
    property string dataParentId: ""
    property var selectionList: []
    signal selectionChanged()
    height: parent.height

    function getSelectionList() {
        return selectionList;
    }

    function insertRecord(dataId, dataName, dataParentId) {
        dataTable.push([dataId, dataName, dataParentId]);
    }

    function insertRecords(records) {
        for (const [dataId, dataName, dataParentId] of records)
            insertRecord(dataId, dataName, dataParentId)
    }

    function selectRecords(dataParentId) {
        return dataTable.filter(d => d[2] === dataParentId);
    }

    function selectRecursive(dataParentId) {
        let obj = ({ id :0 ,dataId: dataParentId });

        for (const [dataId, dataName, _dataParentId] of selectRecords(dataParentId)) {
            if (! ("nodes" in obj) ) obj.nodes = [];
            obj.nodes.push({"id" :dataId ,  "dataName" :dataName, "nodes" : selectRecursive(dataId)});
        }
        return obj;
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        clip: true
        radius: 10

        RowLayout {
            id: buttonRowLayout
            implicitWidth: parent.width
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.margins: 20
            spacing: 20

            RoundButton {
                id: expandButton
                implicitWidth: buttonRowLayout.width /2 - 10
                implicitHeight: 30
                radius: 10

                Text {
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    font.pointSize: 10
                    text: "Expand All"
                }

                background: Rectangle {
                    id: expandButtonRect
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    radius: 10
                }

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        appTreeView.expandAll()
                    }
                }
            }

            RoundButton {
                id: collapseButton
                implicitWidth: buttonRowLayout.width /2 - 10
                implicitHeight: 30
                radius: 10

                Text {
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                    font.pointSize: 10
                    text: "Collapse All"
                }

                background: Rectangle {
                    id: collapseButtonRect
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    radius: 10
                }

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        appTreeView.collapseAll()
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ScrollView {
            id: treeViewScrollView
            anchors.top: buttonRowLayout.bottom
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            contentHeight: appTreeView.height
            contentWidth: appTreeView.implicitWidth
            anchors.margins: 20
            clip: true

            AppTreeView {
                id: appTreeView
                indentation: 0
            }
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        for (let i = 0; i < dataModel.count; i++) {
            let item = dataModel.get(i);
            insertRecord(item[dataId], item[dataName], item[dataParentId]);
        }
        let m = selectRecursive(0);
        appTreeView.model = m;
    }
}
```

AppTreeView.qml :

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Column {
    id: tv
    property var model
    property int indentation

    function expandAll() {
        //TODO
    }

    function collapseAll() {
        //TODO
    }

    Repeater {
        id : repeater
        model: tv.model ? tv.model.nodes : 0
        delegate: Column {
            id : column
            property bool isChecked: false

            Row {
                id: row
                spacing: 10
                height: 30
                width: childrenRect.width

                Item {
                    id: indentationItem
                    height: parent.height
                    width: indentation
                }

                RoundButton {
                    id: button
                    visible: {
                        var obj = modelData.nodes
                        if (! ("nodes" in obj) ) {
                            return false
                        } else {
                            return true
                        }
                    }
                    radius: 100
                    width: 25
                    height: width
                    text: "V"
                    rotation: isChecked ? 0 : -90
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    anchors.left: indentationItem.right

                    background: Rectangle {
                        radius: 100
                    }

                    onClicked: {
                        isChecked = !isChecked;
                        if (isChecked) {
                            expand(modelData.nodes);
                        } else {
                            collapse();
                        }
                    }
                }

                CheckBox {
                    id: checkBox
                    checked: isItemSelected(modelData)
                    onCheckedChanged: {
                        if (checked === true) {
                            addToSelection(modelData);
                        } else if (checked === false){
                            removeFromSelection(modelData);
                        }
                    }
                    anchors.left: button.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: 10
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                }

                Rectangle {
                    id: rect
                    width: childrenRect.width
                    height: 30
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    radius: 10
                    anchors.left: checkBox.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: 10

                    Text {
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                        id: text
                        text: modelData.dataName
                    }
                }
            }

            Loader {
                id: loader
            }

            function expand(modelData) {
                loader.setSource(
                            "AppTreeView.qml",
                            { model: modelData,
                                indentation: indentation + 30
                            }
                            );
            }

            function collapse() {
                loader.source = "Blank.qml";
            }

            function addToSelection(modelData) {
                if (!isItemSelected(modelData)) {
                    console.log("Adding", modelData.dataName, "to selection");
                    selectionList.push(modelData.id);
                    selectionChanged();
                }
            }

            function removeFromSelection(modelData) {
                var index = selectionList.indexOf(modelData.id);
                if (index !== -1) {
                    console.log("Removing", modelData.dataName, "from selection");
                    selectionList.splice(index, 1);
                    selectionChanged();
                }
            }

            function isItemSelected(modelData) {
                return selectionList.includes(modelData.id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And Blank.qml display nothing :

```
import QtQuick 2.13
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5

Item {
}
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Since **Qt 6.3**, there is a [`TreeView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-treeview.html) which you can use. If you can upgrade to **PySide 6**, it's better than rewriting it from scratch.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working with already existing code based on 5.15 and cannot switch to 6.3.

Comment: Your sample code does not adhere to MRE properties. However, if you have the path where you want to expand, you can use a while loop to traverse to that point. Here is an example: `while (node) { node = node.children.find(/* find child by id */); node.expand(); }`. Also, if you provide a minimal sample code, I can offer a better answer. For the recursive aspect, you can also refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77721513/11603485.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! By minimal sample code, do you want me to synthesize as much as I can my code ?

Comment: I tried to test your code, but you didn't provide the triangle icon, and it is undefined. Additionally, there are many color variables that are not defined anywhere in your sample code. In short, your source code is not runnable and cannot be tested. It would be helpful to have a simpler sample code so that other users can easily try your code and provide a solution.

Comment: Hey @smr, I understand and apologize for not providing it like this in the first place. I just edited my code, so it should work for everyone as there is no more custom icons or colors.

Comment: And how can I determine the contents of the `customerDataModel`?

Comment: `customerDataModel`, or any used dataModel, contains 3 fields, as declared in my main.qml when calling my `OctopusTreeView.qml` component : "CustomerID", "CustomerName" and "CustomerParentID", which is used to handle heredity between data.
I just edited my code and added a simple example of the kind of data I have in `customerDataModel` :)

Comment: I posted my answer, but there wasn't any feedback from you. Does it answer what you needed?

Comment: @smr Sorry, I saw your response but I haven't had the time yet to implement and test it in my code. As soon as I've tested it, I'll give you feedback. Thanks again for helping me and giving your time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, I do not recommend this structure for a tree view solution. There are much better options available to display a tree view.

In this answer, I have attempted to keep the base code intact and just added functions such as `expandAll`, `collapseAll`, and `expandPath`, along with some other modifications.

- `expandAll` is a recursive function that calls `expandAll` for all children.
- `collapseAll` just hides and collapses the base children. Based on the current approach, this would destroy the child items, resetting them to the collapsed state.
- `expandPath` takes an array of IDs from the root to a specific child. For example, for (id: 5), `[2, 4, 5]` should be provided. This array can also be retrieved from the `pathToId` function in `OctopusTreeView`.

*expandPath Function:*

Here, I have also used a recursive approach and called `expandPath` for inner children if the child is found.
I also have used a trick to filter and convert `visibleChildren` into a JavaScript array.

To expand an item, you only need to set `isChecked = true`, and the item will expand.

```js
function expandPath(path) {
    if (path && path.length) {
        const current = path[0];
        const nodes = Array.from(visibleChildren).filter(n => 'nodes' in n);
        const node = nodes.find(n => n.nodeId == current);

        if (node) {
            node.isChecked = true; // Expand node

            const innerItem = node.loader.item;
            if (innerItem.expandPath) innerItem.expandPath(path.slice(1));
        }
    }
}
```

##### Other Modifications:

In my opinion, the current code requires significant refactoring. However, I have made some changes to make the source code cleaner and shorter:

- Use `component` for inline reusable items.
- Avoid using anchors inside Row/Columns/Layouts.
- Avoid using `MouseArea` inside buttons; they already have `onClicked` and other signals.
- Use `palette` to change the color of `Control` components.
- Make buttons checkable, if applicable.
- etc.

**main.qml**

```
palette { // Try using palettes in Qt 5 to set button and window colors.
    base: '#badfd7'
    window: '#f1f2f3'
    button: '#60bfc1'
    highlight: '#fdb7b9'

    text: '#343536'
    windowText: '#343536'
    buttonText: '#f1f2f3'
    highlightedText: '#343536'
}

ListModel { /* ... */}
OctopusTreeView { /* ... */ }
```

**OctopusTreeView.qml**

```
Page {
    id: page

    property var dataTable: ([])
    property var dataModel: []

    property string dataId: ""
    property string dataName: ""
    property string dataParentId: ""
    property var selectionList: []
    signal selectionChanged()

    function getSelectionList() {
        return selectionList;
    }

    function insertRecord(dataId, dataName, dataParentId) {
        dataTable.push([dataId, dataName, dataParentId]);
    }

    function insertRecords(records) {
        for (const [dataId, dataName, dataParentId] of records) {
            insertRecord(dataId, dataName, dataParentId);
        }
    }

    function selectRecords(dataParentId) {
        return dataTable.filter(d => d[2] === dataParentId);
    }

    function selectRecursive(dataParentId) {
        let obj = ({ id :0 ,dataId: dataParentId });

        for (const [dataId, dataName, _dataParentId] of selectRecords(dataParentId)) {
            if (! ("nodes" in obj) ) obj.nodes = [];
            obj.nodes.push({"id" :dataId ,  "dataName" :dataName, "nodes" : selectRecursive(dataId)});
        }

        return obj;
    }

    function pathToId(id) {
        let path = [];

        while(id) {
            const target = dataTable.find(([i, n, p]) => i === id);
            if(target) {
                path.unshift(id);
                id = target[2];
            } else {
                return undefined;
            }
        }

        return path;
    }

    spacing: 5
    padding: 5

    component HeaderBtn: RoundButton {
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true

        radius: 3
        font.bold: true
    }

    header: Control {
        height: 35
        padding: 3
        contentItem: RowLayout {
            spacing: 3

            HeaderBtn {
                text: "Expand All"
                onClicked: appTreeView.expandAll();
            }

            HeaderBtn {
                text: "Collapse All"
                onClicked: appTreeView.collapseAll();
            }

            HeaderBtn {
                text: "Expand id: 5 (Amazon FR)"
                onClicked: appTreeView.expandPath(pathToId(5) ?? []);
            }
        }
    }

    contentItem:  ScrollView {
        id: treeViewScrollView
        implicitHeight: contentHeight
        clip: true

        AppTreeView {
            id: appTreeView
            indentation: 0
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        for (let i = 0; i < dataModel.count; i++) {
            let item = dataModel.get(i);
            insertRecord(item[dataId], item[dataName], item[dataParentId]);
        }
        appTreeView.model = selectRecursive(0);
    }
}
```

**AppTreeView.qml**

```
Column {
    id: tv
    property var model
    property int indentation

    function expandAll() {
        const nodes = Array().filter.call(visibleChildren, n => 'nodes' in n)
        nodes.forEach(n => {
            n.isChecked = true; // Expand node

            const innerItem = n.loader.item;
            if(innerItem && innerItem.expandAll) innerItem.expandAll();
        });
    }

    function collapseAll() {
        const nodes = Array().filter.call(visibleChildren, n => 'nodes' in n)
        nodes.forEach(n => {
            /// Based on the current solution, the inner items get destroyed, so there is no need for recursive traversal.
            n.isChecked = false;
        });
    }

    function expandPath(path) {
        if(path && path.length) {
            const current = path[0];
            const nodes = Array().filter.call(visibleChildren, n => 'nodes' in n)
            const node = nodes.find(n => n.nodeId == current);

            if(node) {
                node.isChecked = true; // Expand node

                const innerItem = node.loader.item;
                if(innerItem.expandPath) innerItem.expandPath(path.slice(1));
            }
        }
    }

    Repeater {
        model: tv.model ? tv.model.nodes : 0
        delegate: Column {
            property alias isChecked: button.checked
            property alias loader: loader

            property string nodeId: modelData.id
            property string nodeName: modelData.dataName
            property var nodes: modelData.nodes

            Grid {
                spacing: 5
                width: childrenRect.width
                verticalItemAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter

                leftPadding: indentation + (button.visible ? 0 : (25 + spacing))

                RoundButton {
                    id: button
                    visible: "nodes" in modelData.nodes
                    checkable: true
                    radius: 5
                    width: 25; height: width
                    text: isChecked ? "-" : "+"
                    font.bold: true

                    onCheckedChanged: checked ? expand(nodes) : collapse();
                }

                CheckBox {
                    padding: 0
                    spacing: 0
                    checked: isItemSelected(modelData)
                    onCheckedChanged: checked ? addToSelection(modelData) :removeFromSelection(modelData)
                    indicator{ width: 25; height: 25 }
                    Component.onCompleted: indicator.radius = 3
                }

                Label {
                    id: text
                    text: nodeName
                    padding: 5
                    background: Rectangle {
                        border { width: 1; color: palette.mid }
                        radius: 3
                    }
                }
            }

            Loader {
                id: loader
            }

            function expand(modelData) {
                loader.setSource("AppTreeView.qml", { model: modelData, indentation: indentation + 30 });
            }

            function collapse() {
                loader.source = "Blank.qml";
            }

            function addToSelection(modelData) {
                if (!isItemSelected(modelData)) {
                    console.log("Adding", modelData.dataName, "to selection");
                    selectionList.push(modelData.id);
                    selectionChanged();
                }
            }

            function removeFromSelection(modelData) {
                var index = selectionList.indexOf(modelData.id);
                if (index !== -1) {
                    console.log("Removing", modelData.dataName, "from selection");
                    selectionList.splice(index, 1);
                    selectionChanged();
                }
            }

            function isItemSelected(modelData) {
                return selectionList.includes(modelData.id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @smr, I finally had the time to test your code and implement it into my application, and it works perfectly! Thanks for your time and your valuable help :)